# insert relative path for saving a zip file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip

I wrote this function for creating a zip archive

```
protected void ImageButton_documenti_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {     
        string path_cartella = @"d:\work\project1\temp\document";
        string path_cartella_zip = @"d:\work\project1\temp\document_zip\";
        path_cartella_zip = path_cartella_zip + "zip_documenti_al_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".zip"; 
        //al click dell'immagine creo un file zip contenente tutte le cartelle dei documenti
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            try
            {
                zip.AddDirectory(path_cartella);
                zip.Comment = "This zip was created at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
                zip.Save(path_cartella_zip);
                operazione_ok.Visible = true;
                operazione_ok.InnerText = "Procedura di zip attivata.";

            }
            catch (Exception errore)
            {
                elenco_errori.Visible = true;
                elenco_errori.InnerText = errore.Message;
            }   
        }
    }
```

this function work fine in local but on my web server I don't know the absolute path and I want to change the "string_path_cartella" and "string_path_cartella_zip" for saving document with a relative path in "temp/document" folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string path_cartella = Server.MapPath("~/temp/document");
string path_cartella_zip = Server.MapPath("~/temp/document_zip");
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx